# I cannot login to my WordPress account

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, networking, xampp

I created a site using WordPress and XAMPP, I can log into my account through my pc but when I try to do the same with my mobile (same network)(accessing localhost of my pc where website is located) I can surf my site but can't login. I guess this is because WordPress database encrypts their passwords before saving it to database. When tried to access site from my Laptop (same network) I was able to login.

To verify this I created another site using XAMPP and basic coding (without WordPress). I was able to login to my account using both mobile and pc (password datatype was varchar).

Then I changed the password datatype to md5 instead of varchar, now I am facing the same problem. I can login with my pc and laptop but cannot do the same with my mobile. Again Laptop worked. I can even modify the database (using phpmyadmin) while surfing from mobile or even by filling forms on the website itself.

Why is this happening only with mobile? I don't want to change my password datatype to varchar because I want it to be encrypted. I want to know why this is happening and is there anyway to solve this problem on mobile without changing the password datatype.

Comment: Just as an FYI, MD5 is neither encryption (it's a hash), nor is it secure

Comment: I'm not sure the second website you've created to investigate the problem proves what you think it does. If you can log in to WordPress using a desktop machine but you can't on a mobile phone, then the issue is not likely to be the password, since this comparison is done on the server side, and so should be identical. Perhaps there is some JavaScript in the theme that is not running correctly on mobile?

Comment: What browser you are using should have no effect on how backend SQL code works. You will almost certainly need to share your code for anyone to do any debugging.

Comment: Also, AFAIK `MD5` isn't a datatype in SQL. Are you sure that's actually the type of your field and not just the function you are calling on the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 is not a data type. `varchar` is a data type and your password is probably `varchar`. On server-side you need to log `json_encode($_POST)` on the receiving end. And check out what is received when you try to log in from laptop and what is received when you log in from your mobile.

Case1: There is no log after you attempted to log in from mobile: The code which you expect to run is not being executed. In this case you need to find the code which is executed instead and fix any bugs in it.

Case2: The data logged for laptop is significantly different from the data logged for mobile. In this case you need to analyze the differences and fix any bugs.

Case3: The data logged for laptop is similar to the data logged for mobile. In this case you need to check your server-side code and find out how mobile is being handled differently.